# When i tried to enter npm start it is showing the error like this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-start

When i tried to enter npm start it is showing the error like this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvEL.png)

[I tried to execute npm start and it was shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvEL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this process:

1. It seems that you did not install `react-script` in your node module, so try this:

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

2. then, apply `npm install`
3. and finally `npm start`